# NullPointerException in startIntentSenderForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, google-drive-api

I want to upload image to GoogleDrive, and i use example from [GitHub(QuickStart)](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java)
.I invoke method **uploadFileToDrive**, that locates in help-class, extends from MainActivity.

```
    void uploadFileToDrive(final Bitmap bitmap)
{
    Drive.DriveApi.newContents(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(ContentsResult res) {
             OutputStream outputStream = res.getContents().getOutputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
                try {
                    outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Clients.prt("FirstException");
                }
                MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();

                IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                        .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                        .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                        .setInitialContents(res.getContents())
                        .build(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient);

                try {
                   startIntentSenderForResult( //Exception from this line
                            intentSender, 0, null, 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


}
```

But i get NullPointerException:

> 04-22 12:22:52.548: W/System.err(2377): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-22 12:22:52.558: W/System.err(2377):     at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResultInner(Activity.java:3499)
>   04-22 12:22:52.558: W/System.err(2377):     at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:3476)
>   04-22 12:22:52.588: W/System.err(2377):     at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:3443)
>   04-22 12:22:52.588: W/System.err(2377):     at com.example.mathdirectory.materials.DriveHelper$2.onResult(DriveHelper.java:128)

The connect to GoogleDrive is correct, i can get image. Please, help, what is problem?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing at a glance.  intentSender is non-null?

Comment: I have found mistake ) i take the instance of Context-class from MainActivity class, that extends Activity, and invoke startIntentSenderForResult as:

Comment: ((Activity)context).startIntentSenderForResult